# How to show an active link with jquery when i have an animation on hover?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

UPDATE: I have the padding staying but now when i click on another link they are both highlighted and have the padding. How do i fix that? I doesnt seem to remove the class or sth. Thanks for all your help!

```
{
//animation for secondary content what we do page list items
$('#secondary_content_what_we_do li a').hover(function() {
   if(!$(this).hasClass("current")){
       $(this).stop()
       .animate({"paddingLeft":"10px"}, 400) 
       .addClass('column_hover');
    }
}, function() {
   if(!$(this).hasClass("current")){
       $(this).stop()
       .animate({"paddingLeft":"0px"}, 'slow')
       .removeClass('column_hover');
    }
});


$('#secondary_content_what_we_do li a').click(function () {
$('a').removeClass('column_active').removeClass('current');
$(this).addClass('column_active').addClass('current');
var url = $(this).attr('href');
$('#loading_content').hide().load(url).fadeIn(1000);
return false;
});
}
```

Comment: Could explain what you mean by 'im a trying to show an active link with jquery'? Cheers.

Comment: Yes! when i hover over a link I have the padding animating 10px so it pushes the link to the right and a grey background. When i hover off the link the background stays BUT the padding animates back to 0px. I want it to stay at 10px to show an active state on that link. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

and that's the question?

Try to help... Maybe you forgot to add `e.preventDefault()`

Maybe problem is that you use `'#secondary_content_what_we_do li a'` in first handler and `'#secondary_content_what_we_do a'` in second.

**Update:** 
simple solution:

```
$('#secondary_content_what_we_do li a').hover(function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass("current")){
       $(this).stop()
       .animate({"paddingLeft":"10px"}, 400) 
       .addClass('column_hover');
    }else{
        // any other animation
    }
}, function() {
   if(!$(this).hasClass("current")){
       $(this).stop()
       .animate({"paddingLeft":"0px"}, 'slow')
       .removeClass('column_hover');
    }else{
        // any other animation
    }
});

//loads external html page 
$('#secondary_content_what_we_do a').click(function () {
    $('a').removeClass('column_active').removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass('column_active').addClass("current");
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#loading_content').hide().load(url).fadeIn(1000);
    return false;
});

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! My problem is that after i click the link and hover off the padding animates to 0. I want it to stay at 10px.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time Falcon :). I will try it and post a msg here with what i have done. It feels great to be part of the programming world :D i am just getting into it and i love it and excited